# Why isn't my div elements lining up?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 65 columns. I also need to allow the user to adjust the width of the columns. So I overlay a transparent div over the table, subtracting widths of any scrollbars, so just over the table body.

Then I create div elements in this overlay div with a left style based on the cumulative widths of the table columns.

This is great for tables that have 25 or fewer columns. But then the overlayed div elements start to mis align.

Here is the code which creates the div elements:

```
$rootScope.recalcDivs = function (table, grips) {
  var divs = '';
  var left = -table.scrollLeft;
  var headerRow = table.children[0].children[0];
  var columns = headerRow.children.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < columns; ++i) {
    left += $rootScope.parseWidth(headerRow.cells[i].style.minWidth);
    divs += "<div class='" + i + "' style='border-right: solid 1px red; position: absolute; cursor: e-resize; height: " + grips.style.height + "; left: " + left + "px;'></div>";
  }

  grips.innerHTML = divs;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS so that we can reproduce your issue and provide a working solution.

Comment: I added a small fudge factor to the left calculation: -0.15. Seems to line up just about perfectly.